# How to change Ball-Joint with No Motor

Tags: suspension, camaro

I have a 1970 Camaro and put the wrong Ball-Joint in the upper control arm. Does anyone have an idea on how to change it without a motor? I can't drill a hole in the garage floor to anchor the frame. I'm thinking a ratchet strap or maybe a boomer to compress it. Any suggestions would great. This project is more  complicated; I've read that the model before 1970 1/2 are actually a 1969 frame until model change in the spring of 1970. I have a 69 Ball-joint (it was a different part#) coming tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to go down to AutoZone or the like and rent a spring compressor from them. Charge is minimal (if anything ... some places allow you to borrow with a deposit). I would not try to use a rachet strap, as it would have a high likelihood of slipping and allowing the spring to fly out ... Well maybe not, since the shock goes down the middle of it, but it would not be pretty.